# GPU overheat while in linux textmode

Tags: linux, graphics-card, gpu, cooling

I just put an old Nvidia 6600 GT card in my server that is only running in text mode (debian/linux console) but the sensors show a 101-105°C temperature.

The card has only passive cooling (no fan).

Do I have a way to make it go in some kind of "sleep mode" ? I very rarely look at the screen (once a year or so).

I really don't understand why it is so "stressed".

Comment: Are you sure the temperature is accurate?

Comment: Try Cestarian's solution, but if that won't work, there may be hardware problem. Unfortuantely, graphics cards from that time (and many, many more) exhibited similar symptoms due to substandard manufacture. It is quite possible that due to old age and those faults the card is on it's last legs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have a problem like this with a switchable graphics laptop (the laptop always ran both graphics cards at full power in the terminal and the laptop would overheat)

It was a radeon card, but for me the answer was to disable modesetting.

You can try adding the following to your kernel parameters:

```
nouveau.modeset=0
```

Or you can blacklist the nouveau module (in most linux distros I'm familiar with: **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklists.conf**)

```
blacklist nouveau
```

Sorry that I don't have any info on what exactly this does or how exactly it works, but it should solve your problem in my experience. If it doesn't, the only solution is to add active cooling to your card.

Comment: Thanks Cestarian, this helped a lot. I can't fetch the exact temperatures anymore, of course, but external measurements show a ~20°C drop.

Comment: You're welcome, but be aware of the drawback that without modesetting you won't be able to run a GUI environment like X11. (I suggest if you need to do this, you use the proprietary drivers. I suspect they are better for power management and keeping the card at sane temperatures either way; although for a card that old, you may need to use a legacy version of the nvidia drivers.)

Comment: I hope I will never be forced to use a GUI on a server. I only use the video card in case of crash or misconfiguration. But you give me an idea : I will remove it completely and keep it next to the server if I really need it some day.